# First time trying to replace my own tubes- I can't tell what I'm doing wrong sizing wise

Tags: innertube

I'm trying to replace the tube I had on a 700c x 28c tire (picture attached so y'all can make sure I'm definitely reading that correctly).

[image]

My previous tube was a Kenda tube marked 700x28-35c, worked great. Ordered what I thought was the same tube off amazon (probably my mistake for ordering off amazon), and this tube is way thicker than the original and definitely doesn't fit in the tire. The second picture shows how the new tube fits in the tire, the third shows a comparison between the tube I had in the tire (the inner tube that's smaller and thinner) and the new one (the outer tube that's much thicker).

[image]

[image]

I don't have any local bike shop that I can go to in person, so I'm stuck ordering tubes online-- what should I do to make sure that I'm getting the right kind of tube (ie- things to look out for that may indicate I'm getting a tube that's too thick like what happened to me).

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What happens if you let half the air out of it?  Without a tire to constrain it, a tube can inflate quite a lot if you pump too much air into it; it just needs barely enough to not flop around.

Answer (score 5):

Your new tube is labelled as the correct size, so you ordered the right thing.

It looks to have some air in it while installing, try fully deflating the tube and let it "relax" back to normal size.  Then compare the old and new tubes for length/circumference.

If the new one is just a little long, you can carefully spread it around the inside of the tyre being careful to avoid folds.

If the new tube is just too long, it is probably going to fold, and has either been mislabelled or is higher in the sizing range (like a pair of pants, size X can vary a bit)  In this case its probably better suited for an old 630 wheel rather than your 622 common-sized road bike wheel.  I'd give it  away to someone with an old wheel and buy a couple of good-fitting tubes.  Continental are excellent brands, as are budget Lifeline.

Amazon is not a bike shop.  Consider checking another source, like wiggle or bike24 or any number of other online stores.